# Gamblers ruin formula

Tags: probability, statistics, game-theory, gambling

**Hello ,** **I have been reading about gamblers ruin and I found this formula

can anyone confirm its accuracy ?   I assume they only bet one chip a time**

[image]

Comment: I can confirm the accuracy of it. But are you trying to understand where it comes from? And yes it usually the first model where its $\pm 1$ unit (could be dollar amount, as this is where I first came across this classic)

Comment: Can this formula be used this way ........

Comment: Can this formula be used this way ........im in a casino and I have 60 chips- I want to get to 100 chips then I walk away . so I want to win 40 more . so  anne has 60 chips and carol has 40 chips . can this formula work out this question?

Comment: You can work out the relative probablities of you getting to 100 before your counterpart gets to 100z as to expected time before you get to leave is another matter. This is assuming its a $\pm 1$ chip increments.

Comment: obviously my chances of winning would be different

Comment: Yup. As the formula shows it depends on your starting capital/chips. So the bigger the differential between players starting capital the better the odds. You remember "the house always wins" statement? With slight advantages in probabiliry..they also have deeper pockets (and table limits).

Comment: ive just plugged in the question , I have 60 and I want to win 40 , the house has 2% edge my chance are ....Player 1 Probability of Ruin = 0.9596  --- I am staying away from casinos!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To derive that formula, let $A(n)$ be the probability that Anne wins if she started with $n$ coins; clearly $A(32) =1$ since Carol has nothing to bet, and $A(0) = 0$ since Anne has nothing to bet.  We are looking to determine $A(23)$.

Equally clearly, if $0 < n < 32$, then after one betting outcome the players are playing the same game but with a starting $n$ which is one different from the original $n$, so for $0 < n < 32$,
$$
A(n) = \frac{5}{12} A(n+1) + \frac{7}{12} A(n-1) = pA(n+1)+qA(n-1)
$$
which we can re-arrange (by solving for $A(n+1)$) to
$$
A(n+1) =  \frac{1}{p}A(n) - \frac{q}{p}A(n-1) = \frac{p+q}{p}A(n) + \frac{q}{p}A(n-1)
\\ 
 A(n+1) = A(n)+\frac{q}{p} \left[ A(n) - A(n-1) \right] 
$$
Now let's look in particular at the *difference* $A(2)-A(1)$ (this is the clever step in the proof):
$$
 A(n+1) - A(n)=\frac{q}{p} \left[ A(n) - A(n-1) \right] 
$$
$$
A(2) - A(1)  =  pA(2)+qA(0) =  \frac{q}{p} \left[ A(1) - A(0) \right] =  \frac{q}{p}A(1)
$$
and then
$$
A(3) - A(2)  =  \frac{q}{p} \left[ A(2) - A(1) \right] = \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^2 A(1) \\A(4) - A(3)   = \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^3 A(1) 
 $$
and eventually $$ A(32) - A(31) = \left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{31} A(1)$$
But that means (by telescoping the differences) that 
$$A(32) = \sum_{i=1}^{31}\left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{31} A(1)$$ and of 
of course $A(32) = 1$ from above.

The geometric sum for the expression for $A(32)$ can be expressed in closed form, and this gives an equation which can be solved for $A(1)$.  That in turn leads to the formula for all the $A(n)$, which is the formula you were concerned with.

Comment: This is just brilliant in comparison to system-of-equation-type proof!

Comment: Isn't the result :
$ A(32) = \sum_{i=1}^{31}\left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{i} A(1) $

Instead that: 
$ A(32) = \sum_{i=1}^{31}\left( \frac{q}{p} \right)^{31} A(1) $ ?